# How to redirect angular 4 route based on conditons

Tags: angular, redirect, conditional-statements, angular4-router

Depends on the user type, I have to redirect to the pages when the path is empty. Hence, I tried in the following way.

```
export const Approutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {
        path: 'locals',  component: LaunchScreenComponent,
          children: [
            {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeScreenComponent,
          },
          {
              path: 'change-password',
              component: ChangePasswordComponent
          }
        ]
      }
];
if(Approutes[0].path.length == 0){
  if(sessionStorage.authToken){
    if(sessionStorage.user1 == 'true'){
       Approutes[0].redirectTo = '/user1/manage';
   } else if(!sessionStorage.user1 && sessionStorage.user2 == 'false'){
     Approutes[0].redirectTo = '/user2/listing';
  } else{
    Approutes[0].redirectTo = '/locals/home';
  }
 } else {
    Approutes[0].redirectTo = '/locals/home';
 }
}
```

[image]
 It worked. But, It will give error when i build for prod. error is: There should be any one of redirectTo or component bla bla..
Could anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing:

```
export const Approutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'locals',  component: LaunchScreenComponent,
      children: [
        {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeScreenComponent,
      },
      {
          path: 'change-password',
          component: ChangePasswordComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
if(sessionStorage.authToken){
    if(sessionStorage.user1 == 'true'){
        Approutes.unshift({ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/user1/manage'});
    } else if(!sessionStorage.user1 && sessionStorage.user2 == 'false') {
        Approutes.unshift({ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/user2/listing'});
    } else{
        Approutes.unshift({ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/locals/home'});
    }
} else {
    Approutes.unshift({ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/locals/home'});
}
```

won't effect your flow and will eliminate `prod` error.

Comment: Such a simple technique. I did not try. Thanks for the answer.  Is it the proper way of achieving this? Just to know

Comment: yes, its totally fine way to do this. If you make it in resolve then you will have to make new `navigation` to the required path.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the response. The above-mentioned error is resolved but it is giving cannot read property params of null. Could you please tell me   what is the mistake

Comment: Please check the image I uploaded in question

Comment: Can you make the code available on git or live on stackblitz?